# Remote detection of a trojan - how can it be done?

Tags: virus, detection, trojan

In [this blog post](https://insights.cybcube.com/cyber-catastrophe-meet-enterprise-ransomware-how-the-colonial-pipeline-attack-underscores-the-potential-for-criminals-to-cause-large-scale-losses) CyberCube claim:

> CyberCube observed a malware infection on Colonial Pipeline’s network named “trojan.win32.razy.gen”

I'm really curious to know how this could be done from *outside* Colonial's network. I'm asking in general using this case as an example - please don't post any proprietary information

Thanks,

Comment: How do you know that the detection was external/remote?

Comment: The blog post says so! The dections are labelled "external".

Comment: The word "external" is not mentioned in the article at all. The discussions about the malware do not mention how it was detected.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article doesn't say how that malware was detected, but from the other parts of the article, they used external traffic analysis to come to their other conclusions.

A search for `trojan.win32.razy.gen` shows that it is a malicious browser extension that redirects browser traffic in very specific ways.

So, from these clues, it would be reasonable to conclude that they could have seen this malware's traffic externally.